# Pixi.js: How is this complex series of position/alpha/scale numbers generated?

Tags: javascript, canvas, gsap, pixi.js

Can anyone explain how this file was generated, what is was made with? It's a huge amount of y position, alpha and scale points, one for each frame, for animating sprites on the pixi canvas. Some elements have maybe 800 position points? I'm thinking each y point was not typed individually, but maybe it was :) Seems like it would have been tough to refine the animation if each number was typed rather than generated some other way.

`http://flashvhtml.com/js/site/ScrollMap.js`

For instance:

```
var rockets = {rockets:[{startFrame:0, endFrame:100, position:[1.15,5,3.14,2.25,10,3.14,3.3,15,3.14,4.3,20,3.14,5.3,25,3.14,6.25,30,3.13,7.15,35,3.13,8.05,40,3.13,8.9,45,3.13,9.75,50,3.13,10.55,53,3.13,11.35,54,3.13,12.15,53,3.13,12.9,50,3.13,13.65,45,3.13,14.4,38,3.13,15.1,29,3.13,15.8,18,3.13,16.5,5,3.13,17.2,-9.95,3.13,17.85,-26.9,3.13,18.5,-45.85,3.13,19.15,-66.8,3.13,19.8,-89.75,3.13,20.45,-114.7,3.13,21.05,-141.65,3.13,21.65,-170.6,3.13,22.25,-201.55,3.13,22.85,-234.5,3.13,23.45,-269.45,3.13,24.05,-306.4,3.13,24.6,-345.35,3.13,25.15,-386.3,3.13,25.7,-429.25,3.13,26.25,-474.2,3.13,26.8,-521.15,3.13,27.35,-570.1,3.13,27.9,-621.05,3.13,28.45,-674,3.13,29,-728.95,3.13,29.55,-785.9,3.13,30.05,-844.85,3.13,30.55,-905.8,3.13,31.05,-968.75,3.13,31.55,-1033.7,3.13,32.05,-1100.65,3.13,32.55,-1169.6,3.13,33.05,-1240.55,3.13,33.55,-1313.5,3.13,34.05,-1388.45,3.13,34.55,-1465.4,3.13,35.05,-1544.35,3.13,35.55,-1625.3,3.13,36.05,-1708.25,3.13,36.55,-1793.2,3.13,37.05,-1880.15,3.13,37.55,-1969.1,3.13,38.05,-2060.05,3.13,38.55,-2153,3.13,39.05,-2247.95,3.13,39.55,-2344.9,3.13,40.05,-2443.85,3.13,40.55,-2544.8,3.13,41,-2647.75,3.13,41.45,-2752.7,3.13,41.9,-2859.65,3.13,42.35,-2968.6,3.13,42.8,-3079.55,3.13,43.25,-3192.5,3.13,43.7,-3307.45,3.13,44.15,-3424.4,3.13,44.6,-3543.35,3.13,45.05,-3664.3,3.13,45.5,-3787.25,3.13,45.95,-3912.2,3.13,46.4,-4039.15,3.13,46.85,-4168.1,3.13,47.3,-4299.05,3.13,47.75,-4432,3.13,48.2,-4566.95,3.13,48.65,-4703.9,3.13,49.1,-4842.85,3.13,49.55,-4983.8,3.13,50,-5126.75,3.13,50.45,-5271.7,3.13,50.9,-5418.65,3.13,51.35,-5567.6,3.13,51.8,-5718.55,3.13,52.25,-5871.5,3.13,52.7,-6026.45,3.13,53.15,-6183.4,3.13,53.6,-6342.35,3.13,54.05,-6503.3,3.13,54.5,-6666.25,3.13,54.95,-6831.2,3.13,55.4,-6998.15,3.13,55.85,-7167.1,3.13,56.3,-7338.05,3.13,56.75,-7511,3.13,57.2,-7685.95,3.13]},
```

and also the position, scale and alpha here:

```
    mc89:{view:'cloudFade', depth:3, startFrame:488, endFrame:540, position:[1,1,0.95,1.2,0.95,1.2,0.95,1.2,1,1,0.95,1.2,0.95,1.2,0.95,1.2,0.95,1.2,0.95,1.2,0.95,1.2,0.95,1.2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], scale:[20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718368530273438,15.597808837890625,20.718368530273438,15.597808837890625,20.718368530273438,15.597808837890625,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718368530273438,15.597808837890625,20.718368530273438,15.597808837890625,20.718368530273438,15.597808837890625,20.718368530273438,15.597808837890625,20.718368530273438,15.597808837890625,20.718368530273438,15.597808837890625,20.718368530273438,15.597808837890625,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375,20.718994140625,15.5989990234375], alpha:[0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,0.875,0.75,0.625,0.5,0.375,0.25,0.125,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
```

It kind of looks like skrollr.js meets greensock on steroids. It's from the brilliant http://flashvhtml.com site. Anyhow, I'd like to know how it was put together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash v HTML says that this file was produced using [Adobe Edge Animate](https://creative.adobe.com/products/animate) (it's in their "Findings" section). Back then, it was known for producing "brute-force" animation sheets. I'm not sure if they use a more programmatic approach nowadays, but GreenSock is a much lighter approach to making animations of this sort.

The third video in [this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/edge-animate/how-to/build-web-banner.html) shows the animation process. It'll export the same style of file you linked to, chock-full of x, y, alpha, etc values.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed it had to be something like that, now I see the [An] symbol, though the same section on the flashvhtml site also says they used flash to layout the animation of the site, so then how did they move it into Edge to export it? Can Edge import a fla and export as html5? Yes I also think Greensock may be a better way to go today.